# What are my options in testing iOS devices, for free?

Tags: selenium, appium, ios, selenium-grid

I am very new to ios automation test and I plan to use Appium and selenium grid for parallel tests.

- according to apple, when testing it in a real device i have to have a developer id which costs 99 bucks per year. Now what if I only wanted to test the app using just the emulators in xcode only, is that free?
- if I used xamarin to create tests for both, should I still need a developer id for testing ios?

Comment: Sure it's not an appleid? https://appleid.apple.com/account 
I don't need to pay for anything for my id as I am not distributing stuff, I am just testing.  I'm not familiar with xamarin setup but I just googled and learned it, so now see my answer

Comment: Since I would be using Windows PC as a Hub and Mac as a Node for selenium grid tests, is this possible without me paying for anything when testing?

Comment: @Marj - you may consider waiting a day or so before accepting answer. Sometimes people in different time zone might have a better answer, but would not waste time writing it if you already accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an appleID:
[Check here](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create)

and use [free provisioning:](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/)

Which states that *Free provisioning allows developers to deploy their Xamarin.iOS application to their iOS device without being part of any Apple Developer Program*

See [details here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/)

Comment: Not sure why this is not the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, this is the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1 : what if I only wanted to test the app using just the
>   emulators in xcode only, is that free?

**Answer :**

- Developer ID is mandatory for iOS app development.
- When you are using any app to test, You might be having development team with you. If yes, then you can use Developer ID used for that app
- Its not different for each developer. Its different for each app

> Question 2 : If I used xamarin to create tests for both, should I
>   still need a developer id for testing ios?

**Answer :**

- No, you do not need to have Developer ID for Xamarin

Comment: so I am assuming that the answer will be "I can use the development team's Developer ID" when testing the ios apps in real device. Right now I still don't have the app to test, and I wanted to test the calendar app in the simulator of xcode, is that still possible? Or Developer ID is still needed?

Comment: I have a competing answer but I only care about the right answer and this answer confuses me

Comment: @Marj - Developer ID still needed.